# Finding out the Domain Name of an IP Address using C#

Tags: c#, nslookup

In my application, I should get the domain names of the few IP Addresses I give as Input. I guess this process is called NSLOOKUP. However, I would like to confirm if I'm right. Simple program to implement this and display a MessageBox output is what I look for.

Contributions please...

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: What have you done already? Do you have any piece of code?

Comment: I did.. But I was unable to follow it! Anyway, I'll make a little more keen observation on it and then get back to you @JeremyChild :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(address );
Console.WriteLine(entry.HostName);
```